# Async javascript calls against Flask services run sequentially

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, flask

As a test I created a html page that issues the following $.get requests to my Flask server:

```
http://myflaskapp/api/test1.json  
http://myflaskapp/api/test2.json
```

Both services sleep for 30 seconds.

One would assume the html page would finish loading in 30 seconds because of async calls.  However it takes 60 seconds (they run one after each other which can be seen in the development console/network).

My Flask instance is running on gunicorn using 4 workers and fronted by nginx.

Am I doing something wrong or is this expected behaviour?

Thanks

Comment: jQuery's async calls are not aware of server side technology. So, the problem may only be with client side. Please, show your jquery code, making $.get calls.

Answer (score 1):

Grrr....it was my mistake on my behalf.
The server was actually running a single worker and after I changed the gunicorn command to run 4 workers (it was just running 1 before) then everything ran just fine:
/var/www/myflaskap/env/bin/gunicorn "mytest_service.application:create_app()" -b 0.0.0.0:8000 -w 4